# Eloquent create method returning "id" 0 after storing data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing an strange issue. This is my migration:

```
Schema::create('calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string("start");
    $table->string("end");
    $table->foreignId("learner_id")->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId("driving_instructor_id")->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId("event_type_id")->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId("licence_class_id")->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->text("description")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is my model:

```
class Calendar extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        "id",
        "start",
        "end",
        "learner_id",
        "driving_instructor_id",
        "event_type_id",
        "licence_class_id",
        "description",
    ];

    protected $appends = ["title"];

    public function eventType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EventType::class);
    }

    public function learner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Learner::class);
    }
    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Transaction::class);
    }

    public function drivingInstructor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DrivingInstructor::class);
    }

    public function licenceClass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LicenceClass::class);
    }

    public function getTitleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->learner->full_name;
    }
}
```

When use the create method, it successfully creates a new entry in the database however it is returning and id 0.

```
$calendarIds[]=(Calendar::create($data))->id;
```

The $data variable holds:

```
array:12 [
  "title" => ""
  "start" => "2020-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"
  "startTimezone" => ""
  "end" => "2020-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"
  "endTimezone" => ""
  "recurrenceRule" => ""
  "recurrenceException" => ""
  "isAllDay" => true
  "description" => ""
  "driving_instructor_id" => 3
  "event_type_id" => 1
  "licence_class_id" => 1
]
```

I have never faced this issue before. When i do the same thing with tinker however it returns the correct id. I have tried using the `$calendar->save()` method as well and it is returning id as 0 as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 7

Comment: what do you get from `Calendar::first()->id`?

Comment: Try removing `id` from `$fillable` property on your model

Comment: @lagbox I does give the id of the first post

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Not helping. Actually i added the "id"  later to see if that would fix it.

Comment: that is your exact `Calendar` model? nothing else in it?

Comment: @lagbox yeah nothing else

Comment: What about if you do it in two steps? `$calendar = Calendar::create($data); $calendarIds[] = $calendar->id;`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ that is not helping either. Its rather strange what is happeing.Tried doing $calender = new Calendar() & $calendar-save() as well. Other attributes are correct but the id is still 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of googling I found out that Telescope query watcher was causing the problem. I had to turn off the watcher. Here is the thread https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/289

Answer (score -1):

You should use in the migration script:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Comment: Laravel itself uses $table->id(); on the users migration. I dont think that is the problem